# Implementing a function similar to EXCEL Lookup in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, lookup

I have a lot of code that requires random numbers to be generated and then options selected based on percentage.  I have it working without issue by simply using an implementation of the Mersenne Twister and generating a double between 0 and 100, then assigning results by percentage with select case.  It works fine, but it's very cumbersome and truth be told, I'm tired of continuously writing this out everytime.

I'd much prefer something similar to EXCEL's Lookup Function where you give two arrays such as `LOOKUP(5, {1,10,20,30,40}, {"1-10", "11-20", "21-30","31-40"})`

Which in this case would return: "1-10" since 5 is between 1-10.

Is there an easy way to implement a C#/VB.Net version of this using LINQ?  I'm sure there must be but I'm at a loss for how to implement something like this.  It would be far easier to write this one line of code than long select case statements.

If there is a better way than implementing an equivalent of an EXCEL lookup function, I'd love to know that as well...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your are doing the second form of lookup, as the first would throw an error if the first argument doesn't exactly match an element in the array passed in the second argument.

This should work:

```
Public Function LookUp(Of T)(ByVal value As IComparable, ByVal Values() As IComparable, ByVal Result() As T) As Object
    If Values Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("Values cannot be nothing")
    If Values.Length = 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Values can not be empty")
    If Result Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("Result cannot be nothing")
    If Values.Length = 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Result can not be empty")
    If Values.Length <> Result.Length Then Throw New ArgumentException("Values and Result must have the same length")
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < Values.Length AndAlso value.CompareTo(Values(i)) < 0
        i += 1
    End While
    if i = Values.Length Then i-=1
    Return Result(i)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim Result as string = LOOKUP(5, {1,10,20,30,40}, {"1-10", "11-20", "21-30","31-40"})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do it with LINQ or Array/List .FindIndex, but integer division is probably the best:

```
Dim d = 10.1, a = {1, 10, 20, 30, 40}, b = {"1-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40"}

Dim s1 = b(a.Count(Function(i) i <= d) - 1)

Dim s2 = b(Array.FindLastIndex(a, Function(i) i <= d))

Dim s3 = $"{d - d Mod 10 + 1}-{d - d Mod 10 + 10}"      ' "11-20"
```

Comment: OK, so this works in the 1% of cases where integers are being used.  What happens in the 99% of cases when I use doubles like this: {1.5675, 6.54534, 9.87812, 32.87899, 88.3434,100.1}?  I will almost never design something to fit a "one case" scenario.  Everything I design must work in ALL cases.

Comment: @MattE you can adjust it as you need depending on what the result should be for values that are for example from 10 to 11 or less than 1. Also the first 2 will fail for values below 1 or 40 and above

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with something similar to @Alexander Higgins answer on my own after I sat there and thought about it for a few minutes.  I call it like so:

```
CaseLookup({41, 59, 80, 101}, {"Balanced", "PowerBack", "Receiving", "OneCut"}, 0, 100)
```

Basically I set the boundary for the next item and loop to find the first index it is less than, which means it would fall within that range. I then simply take the same index from the lookup array as the value.

```
Public Shared Function CaseLookup(numArray As Array, lookupArray As Array, minVal As Double, maxval As Double) As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim GetNum As Double = MT.GenerateDouble(minVal, maxval)

        If numArray.Length <> lookupArray.Length Then 'Checks to make sure the arrays are the same length
           Throw New Exception("numArray and lookupArray MUST be the same length!")
           Exit Function
        End If

        For i = 0 To numArray.Length - 1
            If GetNum < numArray(i) Then result = lookupArray(i).ToString()
        Next i
        Return result
    End Function
```